# netty throwing "Failed to mark a promise as success" exception when doing clientRequest

Tags: netty

I have a netty proxy server that is up and running. Once netty receives httpRequest, it does the following

1) The MainHandler#channelRead method creates a FullHttpRequest object which is passed onto another method. In this method, I clone the fullHttpRequest object, modifies the content(body of request), create a client bootStrap with SubHandler and make request with modified object to remote server.
Once this processing done, I let the original request object to proxy to remote server.
What I am observing is if I commented out `invokeAndParseClient` (which is client bootstrap), the proxy works fine.
If I have `invokeAndParseClient` included, I get error (stacktrace below)

NOTE: the exception is thrown from proxyRequest and NOT invokeAndParseClient.

Here is the revelant code

```
class MainHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        FullHttpRequest request = (FullHttpRequest) msg;
        invokeAndParseClient(request);
        proxyRequest(ctx, request);
        }
}


public void invokeAndParseClient(FullHttpRequest request) {
    FullHttpRequest dup = req.duplicate();
     ByteBuf content = dup.content().copy();
    String newContent = modifiedContent(content); //modifies content to String, do some String replacments
    ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(newContent.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    dup.replace(buf); //replace content on the request
    BootStrap b = new Bootstrap()
                .group(bossGroup())
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new RemoteChannelInitializer());
                Channel ch = bootstrap.connect(remoteSocketAddress).sync().channel();
                ChannelFuture f = ch.writeAndFlush(clonedReq);
                //need to close channel. but have to figure out when

}

public class RemoteChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
        p.addLast(new HttpClientCodec());
        p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1024 * 1024, true));
        p.addLast(new ClientHandler()));
    }
}


public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientRequestHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        LOGGER.info("here you gooooo");

        if (msg instanceof FullHttpResponse) {
            LOGGER.info("this is fullHttpResponse");
            FullHttpResponse full = (FullHttpResponse) msg;
            FullHttpResponse dup = full.copy();
            LOGGER.info("response code ===> " + full.status());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With this code, I get the following exception. but once I comment out invokeAndParseClient(request), it works fine.
what is the issue here?

```
2019-05-21 16:08:59.524  WARN 45091 --- [tLoopGroup-3-25] io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer   : Failed to mark a promise as success because it has failed already: DefaultChannelPromise@2e4d789f(failure: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1), unnotified cause:

io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:106) ~[netty-codec-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:801) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:814) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:794) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:837) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1071) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:300) ~[netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
    at com.example.MainHandler.proxyRequest(ClientRequestHandler.java:178) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: I'm seeing your code closes the connection as soon as you confirmed that the other end has received the packet. This means that if the other ends needs some small amount of time to process the request, you will have closed the connection before it even has the chance to send anything back

Comment: I close after future.isSuccess is invoked. Is that not correct?

Comment: Your future is a success after `writeAndFlush` has been done, for a proper http client, you need to follow the following steps: "write request, receive response, close", your code seems to be doing "write request, close", after you close, you cannot receive any more data

Comment: so should I close in channelReadComplete() of the handler?

Comment: @Ferrybig I removed closing the connection code. Now I get a different error, I updated the entire post.

Comment: @Ferrybig related to this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266101/calling-sync-on-channelfuture-is-not-blocking-the-thread

Comment: You get the exception IllegalReferenceCountException when you try to use a reference counted object like http request/respons when it has already been closed by being consumed/not enough opened

Comment: @Ferrybig I got it to work by retaining the original request. Now I have another issue as posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266101/calling-sync-on-channelfuture-is-not-blocking-the-thread